# Java битовый массив

Tags: java, массивы

Есть готовый класс для преобразования целочисленного массива в битовый и обратно?
Конкретно интересует байтовый -> битовый.
Делал так

```
_IS = new byte[corSize];                                          
for (int y = 0, k = 0; y < _Image.Height; y++)    
  for (int x = 0; x < _Image.Width; x++)   
    for (int i = 0, _Mask=128; i < 8; i++,k++,_Mask>>=1)   
       _IS[k] = (byte)((_Image.GetPixel(x, y).R & _Mask) >> (7 - i));
```

Но это очень медленно.

Comment: А где тут результирующий битовый массив? И исходного целочисленного не видно.

Comment: _IS - битовый массив, куда записываю биты, _Image - рисунок, из которого получаю R-компоненту каждого пикселя.

Comment: `_IS` - это *байтовый* массив.

Comment: представляю массив битов в байтовом массиве, в байтовый элемент записывается 1|0

Comment: Значит, формулировка задачи неправильная.

Answer (score 3):

> байтовый -> битовый

Не совсем понятно какое отношение пример имеет к условиям задачи. Но если от него отвлечься, то:

```
import java.util.BitSet;

byte[] bytes = new byte[] { (byte) 0x7F };
BitSet bits = BitSet.valueOf(bytes);
System.out.println("Bits length: " + bits.length());
for (int i = 0; i < bits.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println("bit " + i + ": " + bits.get(i));
}
```

Comment: То что надо, спасибо.